# Javascript : How to dynamic form submit

Tags: javascript, php

i try with below code but it's not working  Please help me if any one know

```
<script>    
function update(i){
    document.myform[i].submit();    
}    
</script>

<?php
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
?>
<form name="myform[]" action="act.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="fname" value="">
    <a href="#" onclick="update(<?php echo $i;?>)">click here </a>
</form>

<?php    
}
?>
```

Comment: Please tell us what do you want to achieve in more detail.

Comment: Show us what you have tried, there are plenty of tutorials / guides on how to submit a form with javascript.

Comment: Please check update code

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
?>
<form name="myform<?php echo $i;?>" action="act.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="fname_<?php echo $i;?>" id="fname_<?php echo $i;?>" value="">
    <a href="#" id='<?php echo $i;?>' onclick="update(<?php echo $i;?>)">click here </a>
</form>
<?php
}
?>
<script>
    function update(id){
        var formName = jQuery(id).closest('form').attr('name')
          alert(formName);
    }
</script>
```

or js:

```
<script>
    function update(id){
        var el = document.getElementById(id);
        var r3 = el.closest("form");  
        console.log(r3);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: try it but jquery error but in need only javascript

Comment: Which was error are you getting and why javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Just change the link for an input of type submit:

```
<form name="myform[]" action="act.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="fname" value="">
    <input type="submit" name="aname" value="click here">
</form>
```

It will automatically submit the form where is contained, no need for this javascript:

```
<script>    
function update(i){
    document.myform[i].submit();    
}    
</script>
```

Edit:

in order to submit a form from javascript..

> document.getElementsByName("myForm")[i].submit();

Answer (score 0):

i got solution

```
<script>

function update(i){
    console.log(i);
  //alert(document.myform[i].fname.value);
    var oForm = document.forms[i];
   // alert(document.forms[i].fname.value);
   // alert(oForm.fname.value);
     oForm.submit();
    //document.myform[i].submit();

}

</script>
```